# Using a DOM element that was saved in a cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, object, cookies

I hope I get this question clear.

I am using JavaScript cookies to save data in order to reuse that data on a different page of my site. (first time using cookies)

I am using the standard JS function for cookies.

First I am doing this:
 `createCookie(cookieName1, element, 7);`

wher `element` is a html DOM element. This works fine, but then when I do

```
var result = readCookie(cookieName1);
```

The result variable looks like this: `[object Object]`.

Now I need to get the parent element of that element (or anything else), using jQuery I will do something like:

```
$(result).parent();
```

but I get this error:
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Can any one help me with this? How can this problem be solved?

Thank you.

Comment: Soon or later you reach your cookie limit and you app will not play. Use very small amount of data on cookie, and then connect them with the read data on server, on a database. Also takes too long to load the big cookies, because cookies readed again even when you load images.

Comment: Also I do not think that you can actual save a dom element in the cookie this way, maybe you only save a reference that is not working even on page refress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting "[object Object]" is because the DOM element is being `toString`ed as its stored in a cookie. You can only store strings in cookies. Therefore you can't store a live DOM element in a cookie. How would that even work? You could perhaps store the HTML representation, but in your case you're trying to access its parent. Would you have the browser store the entire state of the document in a cookie?

Storing an element in a cookie is not going to work. Come up with another way of doing whatever you're trying to do.